# What is a switching node island?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, layout, dc-dc-converter

I was reading the LM2734Z [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2734z.pdf) and in the PCB Layout Considerations section, it says "There should be a continuous ground plane on the bottom layer of a two-layer board except under the switching node island."  What is it?

Comment: Link is currently dead: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/85233.pdf In this datasheet it is on page 9, second paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read a bit more about ground bounce. It's basically the area with your switching supply.

http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/41-06/ground_bounce.html

Basically, a switching supply is a noise machine and a solid ground plane can be a bad idea underneath them. I will let you read more from the Analog website because if I could describe it better than them, I'd be working for them.